# Using NHibernate session load method, is there a way to access an entity's id without initializing the proxy?

Tags: nhibernate

According to the docs, session.Load(id)

> returns an object that is an uninitialized proxy and does not actually hit the database ...

This is great as I have a scenario where I want to load an object (that I know exists in the db) and later (within the same session) access the entity's id and usually only the id AND not have the proxy initialized.  It seems to me that if I only access the id of the proxy, it shouldn't have to be initialized.  At least that is what I was hoping but I can't seem to get it to work that way.

Essentially I'm trying to get the following test to pass:

```
[Test]
public void Accessing_loaded_entity_id_should_not_initialize_the_proxy()
{
    // Arrange
    var repo = new NHRepository<Order>();
    var order = new OrderBuilder().Build();

    repo.Save(order);
    repo.Flush();
    repo.Clear();

    // Act
    var fromDb = repo.Load(order.ID);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(order.ID, fromDb.ID);
    Assert.IsFalse(NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(fromDb));
}
```

This test fails here:

> Assert.IsFalse(NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(fromDb));

**Update**
Here's my hbm mapping of the id:

```
<id name="id" access="field">
    <generator class="hilo">
        <param name="column">OrderNextHi</param>
        <param name="max_lo">100</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

Here's my base entity type.  I'm thinking the problem might be here as I copied this a long time ago and didn't put much thought into it.  Let me know what you think:

```
public abstract class SingleIdentityDomainEntity<T> where T : SingleIdentityDomainEntity<T>
{
    private readonly int id;
    private int? _oldHashCode;

    protected SingleIdentityDomainEntity()
    {
        this.id = 0;    
    }

    public virtual int ID
    {
        get { return this.id; }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as T;
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        // handle the case of comparing two NEW objects
        if (other.IsTransient() && this.IsTransient())
            return ReferenceEquals(other, this);

        return other.ID.Equals(this.ID);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Transient objects are not associated with an item already in storage.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool IsTransient()
    {
        return this.ID == 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Must be provided to properly compare two objects
    /// </summary>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Once we have a hash code we'll never change it
        if (_oldHashCode.HasValue)
            return _oldHashCode.Value;

        // When this instance is transient, we use the base GetHashCode()
        // and remember it, so an instance can NEVER change its hash code.
        if (this.IsTransient())
        {
            _oldHashCode = base.GetHashCode();
            return _oldHashCode.Value;
        }

        return this.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your assert actually force a load from the db. Can you see the sql?

Comment: @Mark, Replacing both Asserts with var i = fromDb.ID I was able to verify with sql profiler that yes the select sql statement is generated.

Comment: Could you post the code behind the ID property and also the mapping for the ID proprty from Order?

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. If you want it initialized use Session.Get()

Comment: @Darren The problem is that I don't want it initialized if I just need the id. This is why I'm using Load and not Get as Get will always hit the db. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Mark Perry - I posted my mapping and code behind of the id property.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Gary B - I'm looking but nothing's jumping out at me. Does you class signature really look like this `SingleIdentityDomainEntity<T> where T : SingleIdentityDomainEntity<T>`?

Comment: @Mark Perry - The Order class (and all other entity types) inherit from the SingleIdentityDomainEntity<T> base type. Also, I wasn't even sure if the behavior I want was even possible. Are you telling me that it really is and that I just have something wired up wrong?

Comment: I was just wondering why the generic constraint was a constraint of itself? Should it read: `public abstract class SingleIdentityDomainEntity<T>`? And yes what you are doing is possible.

Comment: @Mark Perry - Thanks. Constraining the generic to be of type SingleIdentityDomainEntity<T> is useful in the Equals method as that method safely casts the obj object to T which is of SingleIdentityDomainEntity<T>.  This could probably be replaced with var other = obj as SingleIdentityDomainEntity<T>;

Comment: Can you post the signature of the Order class just the public class bit please?

Comment: @GaryB let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1072/discussion-between-mark-perry-and-gary-b)

Comment: This may seem like a dumb question, but... if you're Loading the object by its ID, and you only need the ID, then- what do you need the object for? you can just use the ID you've already got. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What's the code for the NHRepository methods? The bug is likely to be there, have you tried using a raw ISession?

Comment: @sJhonny Not a dumb question at all and I wouldn't really say you're missing something. The main reason I'm doing this is that I don't like passing id's into my entity method api's, I would rather use the entity instead. So I would rather do this, orderProcessor.Process(order) than orderProcessor.Process(orderId). This has proven to be beneficial when testing and when the Process method may at times only use the id and other times actually need the object. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon - When I get a chance I'll remove the repositories and use the raw ISession.  I don't think that is the problem as I'm just forwarding the repository load method call onto the session load method but I'll try it to be sure. At this point I at least know I'm doing something wrong as I wasn't even sure that this was supposed to work as I wanted. Thx for the suggestion.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon - Confirmed that using the raw ISession does not make a difference. In fact, the Load method of the repository is just passing the call off to raw ISession.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your implementation of your repository but I think your problem is in the:

```
repo.Clear();
```

line. I guess it clears your session (all cache values are evicted).

Comment: The fact that the Clear() method is evicting all cached values is why I'm calling it. I don't want the order obj to exist in the session when I call Load. When I load it from the repo, I actually want  the proxy. Then my hope is that if I only try and get the id out of the proxy the proxy won't initialize and I won't get a db hit. Obviously if I call a different method on the proxy I would expect a db hit but the id should already be loaded in the proxy because that's what I used as the parameter into the load method. Does that make sense?

Comment: From the nhibernate documentation: **How much does Hibernate load from the database and how many SQL SELECTs will it use? This depends on the fetching strategy. This is explained in Section 19.1, “Fetching strategies”.** This means that you have to set your fetching strategy in you mapping.